# Input a name and a role and get an output of that role with the names

Tags: java

I need to do this for school. Its supposed to be a JAVA project.

So for example, if we give an input:

```
thomas teacher
charlie student
abe janitor
jenny teacher
```

The output will be:

```
teachers,thomas,jenny
students,charlie,
janitor,abe.
```

I am just a beginner so, so far I have this code:

```
   `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = in.nextLine();

    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    //TreeMap treemap = new TreeMap();
    ArrayList<String> admin = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        Boolean s = input.nextLine().equals("Done");
        //treemap.put(line, "admin");
        if(words[1].contentEquals("admin")){
            admin.add(words[0]);
        }
        else if(s == true){
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("admins," + "," + admin);`
```

I was originally using a treemap but I don't know how to make it work so I thought of using an `ArrayList` and eliminating the brackets at the end.

EDIT:

So I now have the code:

```
    HashMap<String, String> teacher = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> student = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> janitor = new HashMap<String, String>();
    System.out.println("Enter a name followed by a role.");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = in.nextLine();
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    String r = name.nextLine();
    while(true){
        if(line.equals(r + " " + "teacher")){
            teacher.put(r, "teacher");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You Can create a HashMap<String, List<String>) where the key of HashMap holds designation and value i.e. array list holds the names

Comment: Array list is a good choice. Notice that each line gives you essentially a value key pair to work with: 'name', 'position'. So if you have three array lists and filter which name goes into each array list by your second value or 'position' you will end up with the three array lists you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the hint because you should do it yourself.

Use a `HashMap<String, List<String>> map` and insert your inputs like below:

```
if(map.containsKey(words[1]))
{
 List<String> list = map.get(words[1]);
 list.add(words[0]);
 map.put(words[1],list);
}
else
{
 map.put(words[1],Arrays.asList(words[0]))
}
```

This way you will get list of `names` corresponding to each types(`student/teacher`) etc.

After that iterate over the `map` and print the `list`.

Comment: I just added the new code I have right now.
From your code, how will the input put the names in the specific roles that they are designated to?

Comment: @Steam Hashmaps store information in a structure with key value pairs. With the key basically being a 'search term' and the value being the actual information you care about. In the above case the map `HashMap<String, List<String>> map`, has it's key being of type `String` which would be the occupation and the values being lists of strings which would store the names. This is a great way to do things if you have A LOT of occupations, but for only 3 it's a bit overkill.

Comment: @luckydog32 I am curious. I don't have a lot of experience with Hashmaps but if you would write the code above using a Hashmap, how would you write it? Can you show it to me please?

Comment: @Steam I updated my answer to include a hashmap implementation. I tried to break down what each step is doing so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think for a small amount of occupations it's reasonable to accomplish this using just array lists. I think the part you are having trouble with is the input structure so I'll help you out with an example of how to do that part and let you handle the filtering on your own:

```
private List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> janitors = new ArrayList<>();

public void seperatePeople(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        //Keep getting the next line in an infinite loop
        String line = in.nextLine();
        if(line.equals("Done")){
            break; //end the loop
        }else{
            //Split on the spaces
            String[] personArray = line.split(" ");
            //Remember each line is structured like : name, occupation
            //So when we split the line the array list we get from it
            //will be in the same order
            putInArray(personArray[0], personArray[1]);
        }
    }

    //Do whatever printing you have to do down here

}

private void putInArray(String name, String occupation) {
    //filter and add to the correct list in here
}
```

If you wanted to implement this using a hashmap the input method would be the same, but instead of putting names into 3 pre-made occupation arraylists you create arraylists and put them inside a hashmap as you go:

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> peopleHashMap = new HashMap<>();

public void seperatePeople(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        //Keep getting the next line in an infinite loop
        String line = in.nextLine();
        if(line.equals("Done")){
            break; //end the loop
        }else{
            //Split on the spaces
            String[] personArray = line.split(" ");
            //Remember each line is structured like : name, occupation
            //So when we split the line the array list we get from it
            //will be in the same order
            putInArray(personArray[0], personArray[1]);
        }
    }

    //You can get all the keys that you created like this
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(peopleHashMap.keySet());

}

private void putInArray(String name, String occupation) {
    if(peopleHashMap.containsKey(occupation)){
        //If the key (occupation in this case) is already in the hashmap, that means that we previously
        //made a list for that occupation, so we can just the name to that list

        //We pull out a reference to the list 
        List<String> listOfNames = peopleHashMap.get(occupation);
        //And then put the new name into that list
        listOfNames.add(name);
    }else{
        //If the key isn't in the hashmap, then we need to make a new
        //list for this occupation we haven't seen yet
        List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
        //We then put the name into the new list we made
        listOfNames.add(name);
        //And then we put that new list with the into the hashmap with the occupation as the key
        peopleHashMap.put(occupation, listOfNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I made the code work! However, the arrayList has brackets. Do you have any easy way of removing those brackets in Java? Also, is there a way to alphabetize the names? Like if a name starts with b, it should come first and from the name that starts with a c even if I typed in the name with a c first?

Comment: Nice! How did you end up implementing your lists? Did you do it with a hashmap or go with separate lists?

Comment: I did it with separate lists! And in the putInArray method, I added the occupation for each person in separate if statements. So if occupation.equals("teachers") it adds in the name in the teachers Arraylist and so on! 

However, I need to alphabetize the names in each group and remove the brackets.

Comment: @Steam Alright sounds like you are well on your way. `Collections` has a built in sorting algorithm you could use, but I think it would be much better practice for you to try to implement your own sorting algorithm. You can try [Bubble Sort](https://youtu.be/8Kp-8OGwphY), which I think is one of the most straight forward algorithms to implement. It's not that efficient but it's one of the first sorting algorithms everyone learns.

Comment: @Steam If anything is unclear about how the input loop works feel free to ask, and good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: I do have one question. Lets say I only input teachers and no students or janitors. How will I not have students and teachers print?

Like for example, if input is:
kevin teacher
abe teacher

So the output should be:
teacher, kevin, abe

But it is:

teacher, kevin, abe
student,
janitor

How do I remove the student and janitor part from there if there is no input for them?

Comment: @Steam You can check the size of each `List`, if the 'size()' is 0, then that list is empty, you can also do this by calling the 'isEmpty()' method, which is a bit more straight forward.